# PHP mysqli query is not returning mysqli_result object on SELECT statement

Tags: php, mysql

I am wondering what I am doing wrong.. I can't seem to figure out why it's not returning back my rows, it's just not echoing out the statements and leaving it blank when I call to "$grow["bName"]". I tried my query and it works fine, it returns two columns, username and bName. Here is my php code:

```
<?php
require ("cfd.php");
require ("header.php");
$username = $_SESSION["username"];
echo $username;
    //run the query
    $gsql = "SELECT babysitter.bName, login.username FROM login INNER JOIN babysitter ON login.b_ID=babysitter.b_ID WHERE login.username = '".$username."';";
    $gres = mysqli_query($db, $gsql);
    $grow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gres);
    echo "<h2>Hello ".$grow["bName"].", Your admin status is ".$_SESSION['admin']."<br>";
    echo $gres->num_rows;
?>


<?php
require("footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: how about testing the query actually ran successfully.

Comment: Your statement will not return a column `bName` as that seems to be a table. You probably need `babysitter` instead.

Comment: @SZenC you have that backwards its table name then colon name

Comment: $db variable seems to be undeclared in this php file. Have you given  the  right value for this variable? you can also enable error reporting.

Comment: The code looks correct. Problem is possibly somewhere else.

Comment: Why that `;` needed at the end of the query?

Comment: The query should be parameterised to prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Please try `$grow[0]["bName"]` OR else you can use this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gres)) 
{
    $row['bNAme'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**first check num rows. And remove ; at the end of the query**

> Try this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($gres) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gres)) {
    echo $row["bName"];

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be

```
 $gsql = "SELECT babysitter.bName, login.username FROM login INNER JOIN babysitter ON login.b_ID=babysitter.b_ID WHERE login.username = '".$username."'";
```

Use this

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($gres) > 0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($gres)) {
    echo $row["bName"];

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

I asked my teacher and she said that the session could have timed out, therefore giving me an empty string when I called to it (`$username = $_SESSION["username"]`). It then would insert nothing into the query and would give me an error.

I am going to implement some code to check if the `$_SESSION["username"]` is empty or not, if it is, then redirect back to the login page. I'll put this on all pages.